# Reading multiple files with the Ruby gem 'Yomu'

Tags: arrays, ruby, metadata

I'm trying to download documents and strip out the document metadata with the Yomu gem, but cannot find guidance for parsing multiple files. The semi working code is below, and should work if you put some pdf files in the same directory as the script.

```
require 'yomu'
dir = Dir.pwd
files = Dir["#{dir}/*.pdf"]

def allpdf(files)
  filearray = []
    files.each do |file|
    filearray << file
  end    
  filearray
end

def metadata(dir, allfiles)
array = []
  allfiles.each do |file|
    yomufile = Yomu.new file
    array << yomufile.metadata["Author"]
    puts array
  end
end

allfiles = allpdf(files)
metadata(dir, allfiles)
```

So when I '*puts array*' it spits out what I would expect. But if I call 'array' outside of the loop, I get a single entry repeated over and over, so I can only assume that the array/yomu hash is being overwritten perhaps. What is the best way to fix this so that I can return a full array for use elsewhere in the application?
Please Note: I suspect this may be a more general Ruby error on my part related to my lack of array skills rather than a Yomu specific issue. Im not sure how else to address this question however.

Comment: The `allpdf` function is meaningless, it's output is basically a copy of the input. `Dir.[]` returns an Array of filenames.

Comment: It shouldn't return a list of filenames, it should return an array of document metadata using yomu. Am I misunderstanding the point? Edit: I see what you are saying, but removing that isnt going to get me any closer to the answer I guess. Ill remove that bit for now, thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: And I was unable to reproduce your issue. I tried your script and it collects metadata of pdf files in the current directory correctly. Both inside and after the loop `array` contains different Strings, each corresponding to a metadata entry in one of the pdf files. (I have jruby 1.7.9 and yomu 0.2.4)

Comment: Tried with more than one file? The issue is that I go from metadata for each file within the directory when I call puts inside the loop, to metadata for only one file when i call it outside the loop.

Comment: Of course :) "Both inside and after the loop `array` contains **different Strings**"

Comment: They shouldn't contain different strings, we are processing the same files. The output should be identical! Or that is what im trying to achieve :)

Comment: I had a bunch of pdfs with the same author, so I listed Last-Modified instead. Both inside and after the loop `array` looks like this: `["2016-02-17T20:56:39Z", "2016-02-24T21:31:41Z", "2016-01-30T00:26:50Z", "2016-02-09T15:15:40Z", "2016-02-13T13:50:32Z", "2016-02-29T19:05:20Z"]`

Comment: Well damnit, its just the order that appears to change - let me test again and ill mark your answer as correct assuming its working :D

Answer (score 0):

Jakub Pavlík was correct, the code was actually working as stated, it just wasn't displaying the output in the way I expected!